# I am using React Native Expo And need to do live background location tracking

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, location

React Native Expo:  Background Location has not been configured. To enable it, add `location` to `UIBackgroundModes` in Info.plistfile

I am using expo-location and trying to do background location tracking.
my app.json under IOS includes this

`"infoPlist": { "UIBackgroundModes": [ "location", "fetch" ],`

I am calling the startLocationUpdatesAsync function as such

` useEffect(() => {
var appLocation = undefined;

```
const startLocationTracking = async () => {
  var opts = {
    accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
    distanceInterval: 1, //meters
  };

  appLocation = await Location.watchPositionAsync(opts, (location) => {
    dispatch(setCurrentLocation(location.coords));
    sendLocationToAPI(location);
  });
  const backgroundLocation = await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync("background-location") 
}`
```

I end up getting this error

`Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Background Location has not been configured. To enable it, add` location`to`UIBackgroundModes `in Info.plist file.`

I Do not know how to get rid of this, but I think I may have to expo eject and switch to cli. If anyone can help so I can avoid this it would be really helpful.